# How to derive $dW = dE$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work, power

From the definition of power:

$$P \ = \ \frac{dW}{dt} \ = \ \frac{dE}{dt}$$

Multiplying both sides by $dt$, we get:

$$dW = dE$$

$1.$ What does this imply?

$2.$ Are there any other (perhaps more rigorous) way of proving this?

Comment: It implies that you are equating $W$ and $E$ up to a function that has no time dependence. What is $W$ and what is $E$ here?

Comment: This question scratches the tip of a very large iceberg.  Search here for questions on work and energy.

Comment: If you ask what $dW = dE$ imeans mathematically: it means $W = E +c$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Work is transferred energy. That's about it: $W=\Delta E$ means that the work $W$ done by a force equals the amount of energy $\Delta E$ that's moved from one (sub)system to another in the interaction. When you write that with differentials, you get $dW=dE$.

Comment: @Fabian I can understand that relationship by either intuition or integrating both sides. But I have one contradictory idea in my mind that $W = E + C$ implies that W and E are both the indefinite integrals of their derivative. As far as I know indefinite integral of a force is energy, and the definite integral is work. How can work, a definite integral, be in the relation of indefinite integral ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking W as work done on the system and E as the change in mechanical energy, the equality implies that when you do work on a body it's mechanical energy will increase by the same amount. The increase in energy could be either in the form of Kinetic energy or Potential energy. (This is strictly on a classical mechanics point of view, and i think you are asking the question from that  area.). For a rigourous approach, try differentiating the basic equation for total energy, that is the sum of kinetic and potential energy.

Answer (score -2):

From thte first law of thermodynamics, considering no heat transfer.

$\Delta U = Q + W$ (internal energy)

$\Delta E = \Delta E_m + Q + W$ (total energy)